# Jquery clone item

Tags: php, jquery

I'm studying the interactive-image-vamp-up with jquery css3 and php script from http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/03/22/interactive-image-vamp-up-with-jquery-css3-and-php/

My question, how to make items clone and get the clone position?

thanks in advance

Comment: Depnds on where you think the clone will end up being inserted really, based on what you've said Starx has the best guess below.

Answer (score 1):

```
var cloned = $("#itemtoclown").clone(); //clone an element
$("body").append(cloned); //Insert it into DOM

//Access the positions like with
var positions = cloned.position();
console.log(positions.top); //Access the top
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get some element's position it must be appended to the HTML DOM tree. Otherwise you will get top: **0** and left: **0**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    position = $('div:first').clone().appendTo(document.body).position();
    alert( 'top:' + position.top + ' left: ' + position.left );
});
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/teneff/zAspw/)